# Почему shared_ptr запрещает неявное преобразование указателя?

Tags: c++, c++11

Этот код не компилируется:

```
std::shared_ptr<MyType> pi = new MyType[5];
```

Вместо этого, так как конструктор `shared_ptr` объявлен `explicit` - приходится писать:

```
std::shared_ptr<MyType> pi(new MyType[5]);
```

Я нахожу это как минимум неудобным.

В чём причины такого дизайна ?

И какой от этого профит ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Допустим у нас есть функция, принимающая умный указатель:

```
void foo(std::shared_ptr<Mytype> data){
    //...
}
```

Тогда такой код приведет к удалению ресурса, хотя мы этого не подразумевали:

```
MyType *object = new MyType();
foo(object);
```

При вызове функции выполнится создание умного указателя, а при выходе из неё он удалит тот объект которым владел. И все это скомпилируется без каких либо предупреждений.

Comment: Замечу, что в данном случае всё будет валидно, если не обращаться к object после вызова foo.

Answer (score 4):

`explicit` нужен для исключения случайных преобразований типов. Например, Ваша функция имеет такой вид:

```
void f(std::shared_ptr<int> p) { ... }
```

И Вы её где-то вызвали так:

```
int i;
f(&i);
```

Не будь конструктор `explicit`, код бы скомпилировался, но Вы бы получили ошибку во время выполнения (в общем случае - неопределённое поведение), т.к. деструктор `std::shared_ptr` вызовет `delete` для объекта, расположенного на стеке.

Для избежания подобных ситуаций конструктор делается явным `explicit`.

В общем случае, опасно иметь возможность **неявно** приводить совершенно любой указатель к типу умного (т.е. владеющего ресурсом) указателя, т.к. заранее неизвестно что из себя представляет переданный адрес. Когда программист **явно** приводит указатель к типу умного, он однозначно сообщает о своих намерениях. Наличие `explicit`  у конструктора класса умного указателя делает это требование обязательным. Причем это актуально для всех типов умных указателей из стандартной библиотеки: [`unique_ptr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr/), [`shared_ptr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr/) и даже уже устаревший [`auto_ptr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/auto_ptr/auto_ptr/) имеют именно `explicit` конструкторы, принимающие тип обычного указателя.

Comment: какие тогда есть варианты передачи умного указателя в функцию ?

Comment: @ampawd выполнить преобразование явно конечно же. Но не в случае со стековой переменной :)

Comment: а как в случае со стековым объектом поступать ?

Comment: @ampawd, конкретно для такого примера можно сделать так: `f(std::shared_ptr<int>(new int(i)));`. И овцы сыты, и волки целы)

Comment: @ampawd стековый объект умрет сам, его не нужно оборачивать в умный указатель.

Comment: @alexolut, думаю он спрашивает как вызвать функцию `f` и передать ей стековый объект.

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb да, скорее это имелось ввиду

Comment: @ampawd не нужно ей передавать стековый объект. Чтобы это понимать нужно просто ознакомиться с причинами появления умных указателей. Грубо говоря, почитать учебник.

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых: в Вашем коде неопределённое поведение, `std::shared_ptr` не умеет(до C++17) удалять массивы с функцией удаления по умолчанию. Поэтому, внутренний указатель будет удалён с `delete`, а не `delete[]`.

Во-вторых, идиоматичным методом создания умных указателей в C++ является использование семейства функций `make_*`. В частности, для `std::shared_ptr` это `std::make_shared`; мало того, что это удобнее, но и в случае с `std::shared_ptr` это ещё и более эффективно(об этом можно почитать в моей [статье](http://scrutator.me/post/2012/01/18/smart-pointers.aspx)).

Вообще, с появлением умных указателей, `new`/`delete` в коде не должно быть, за исключение крайне редких ситуаций, которые, как правило, могут возникнуть при написании собственной библиотеки. Либо же менеджера памяти.

Что касается кокретного вопроса почему: позволение неявного преобразования во владеющий указатель создаёт больше проблем, чем решает. Человек должен явно указывать свои намерения по созданию владеющего указателя.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49423/discussion-on-answer-by-ixsci--shared-ptr---).